# C# BotFramework FormFlow, pass values to an external api

Tags: c#, botframework

I am currently developing a simple c# formflow bot that captures the values and sends those values off to an external api, gets the json data back from the external api and creates Card Attachments based on the results returned. I am making the call to the external api in the OnCompletion delegate as follows, To keep it simple I am not passing any values to the api (For testing purposes)

```
 .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
                {
                    var reply = context.MakeMessage();

                    var carsFromApi = await GetCarsAsync("/api/values");
                    reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                    reply.Attachments = GetCards(carsFromApi);

                    await context.PostAsync(reply);

                    // Tell the user that the form is complete
                })
```

I make the call to the api and store the results in "carsFromApi" , I step into that which is the following code snippet

```
private static async Task<List<Car>> GetCarsAsync(string path)
        {
            List<Car> car = new List<Car>();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                car = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Car>>();
            }

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Car>>();
        }
```

Problem is when I press F10 and go to the next line which is "reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;". The local variable that stored the cars "carsFromApi " is now null. This is the part where it all falls over. I cant pass this "carsFromApi" to "reply.Attachments = GetCards(carsFromApi);" I have tried to store the data in a private variable but that also seems to be null. The external api is working because it just returns a list of static text for now. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the GetCarsAsync method is ending in the if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) path?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment, the problem was with the response status code. Can you post a reply so I can mark this as the answer? I think I will need to open question for the httpClient error : "This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request." This occurs in the constructor of my FormFlow form after the card attachments have been displayed to the user, not sure how to fix this exception.

Comment: Done. I added a few recommendations. Regarding the exception, look in the forums before posting as I'm sure is a pretty common issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are describing it sounds that your code is not existing through the path of the `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)`. Check if that point is reached as I suspect an exception or something is going wrong with the request.

Alternatively, you can try doing the request in the `ResumeAfter<T>` method you specified when calling the `Form` instead of that in the `OnCompletion` delegate